# Digitally selectable filter for the ST7580

Tags: transistors, filter, frequency, power-line-communication

For the [ST7580](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/st7580.pdf), it uses PSK or FSK to send a signal over power lines. In the [design guide](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/71/8d/7f/e6/13/68/46/46/DM00050178.pdf/files/DM00050178.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00050178.pdf) the example is designed for an FSK or PSK signal to be transmitted at 80 kHz see page [23](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/71/8d/7f/e6/13/68/46/46/DM00050178.pdf/files/DM00050178.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00050178.pdf) for reference to the RX filter calculations below.

[image: RX filter calculations]

For my design I would like to send and receive signals across multiple bands. As this is industry related, I will have to stay away from CENELEC Band A. So I would like to make use of CENELEC Band B (102.5 kHz and 117.5 kHz), C (132.5 kHz), D and a part of the FCC Band (147.5 kHz); As the ST7580 can modulate up to 250 kHz but the RX filter need select these frequencies.

I would like to find out if the following sketch is a viable option:

[image]
*This is just a crude drawing, the final design will only use one inductor and the capacitor will be selected with transistors rather than all the filter components.*

The two main components of the filter is C3 and L2. I would like to know if I "take" GND away from the filter via a NPN transistor, will this lead to the effect that I am going for? (Which is to have four RX filters on the same board and simply flick between them with a few pins on my microchip). *Only one transistor will be on at one time.*

**EDIT:** To clarify I am just focusing on the [reception filter](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/71/8d/7f/e6/13/68/46/46/DM00050178.pdf/files/DM00050178.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00050178.pdf), as shown in the figure below boxed in red, for now. This does not have the R5 resistor included, but it is a part of the circuit.

[image]

**I eventually wish to make this a selectable BPF with a few transistors. Is this a valid method of performing this by changing L2 and C3?**

Comment: Your circuit makes no sense and it doesn't contain any information about the net at the top nor the base signals.

Comment: @Andyaka I am not sure what you are referring to, but I have added an image to explain a bit better what I would like to do. Is this method valid for changing the center Frequency of the BPF? See page 24 of the design guide for the filter response centered at 80Khz. I would like to change that to the aforementioned frequencies